# How to group year and reduce object?

Tags: javascript

I want to update the object to only display the most recent year, only one per year.

The current dividends variable is:

```
const data = {
    0: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2012-09-30'
    ],
    1: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2012-12-31'
    ],
    2: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2013-03-31'
    ],
    3: [
        'AAPL',
        0.435714,
        '2013-09-30'
    ],
    4: [
        'AAPL',
        0.435714,
        '2013-12-31'
    ],
    5: [
        'AAPL',
        0.47,
        '2014-09-30'
    ],
    6: [
        'AAPL',
        0.47,
        '2014-12-31'
    ],
    7: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-06-30'
    ],
    8: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-09-30'
    ],
    9: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-12-31'
    ]
};
```

And I would like to update the variable to:

```
const dividends = {
    0: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2012-12-31'
    ],
    1: [
        'AAPL',
        0.435714,
        '2013-12-31'
    ],
    2: [
        'AAPL',
        0.47,
        '2014-12-31'
    ],
    3: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-12-31'
    ]
};
```

**Sorry had to remove code block format because stackoverflow won't let me to post due to error**

Comment: So you want to sort by removing duplicates of `array[1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on year with oldest date in an object. Then get all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = { 0: [ 'AAPL', 0.378571, '2012-09-30' ], 1: [ 'AAPL', 0.378571, '2012-12-31' ], 2: [ 'AAPL', 0.378571, '2013-03-31' ], 3: [ 'AAPL', 0.435714, '2013-09-30' ], 4: [ 'AAPL', 0.435714, '2013-12-31' ], 5: [ 'AAPL', 0.47, '2014-09-30' ], 6: [ 'AAPL', 0.47, '2014-12-31' ], 7: [ 'AAPL', 0.52, '2015-06-30' ], 8: [ 'AAPL', 0.52, '2015-09-30' ], 9: [ 'AAPL', 0.52, '2015-12-31' ] },
    result = Object.values(data).reduce((r,a) => {
      let year = a[2].substr(0,4);
      r[year] = r[year] || [...a];
      r[year] = r[year][2] > a[2] ? r[year]: [...a];
      return r;
    },{});
const dividends = {...Object.values(result)};
console.log(dividends);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I just changed 
```
let year = a[2].substr(0,4);
```
to 
```
let year = new Date(currentValue[2]).getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will be helpful to you..

```js
const data = {
    0: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2012-09-30'
    ],
    1: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2012-12-31'
    ],
    2: [
        'AAPL',
        0.378571,
        '2013-03-31'
    ],
    3: [
        'AAPL',
        0.435714,
        '2013-09-30'
    ],
    4: [
        'AAPL',
        0.435714,
        '2013-12-31'
    ],
    5: [
        'AAPL',
        0.47,
        '2014-09-30'
    ],
    6: [
        'AAPL',
        0.47,
        '2014-12-31'
    ],
    7: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-06-30'
    ],
    8: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-09-30'
    ],
    9: [
        'AAPL',
        0.52,
        '2015-12-31'
    ]
};

var years=[];
var result={};
var count=0;
for(var key in data){
  var arr=data[key];
  var year=arr[2].split("-")[0];
  if(years.indexOf(year)==-1){
    years.push(year);
    result[count]=arr;
    count++;
  }  
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values()` to convert the object to an array, `.filter()` to check if inverted `Boolean` of  `.some()` date string element of original array `Date` object `.getFullYear()` is equal to current element of iteration, `.getMonth()` is greater than current element, and `.getDate()` is greater than or equal to current element, pass resulting array to `Object.assign()` to set each array as a 0-based property of a JavaScript plain object

```js
const data = {"0":["AAPL",0.378571,"2012-09-30"],"1":["AAPL",0.378571,"2012-12-31"],"2":["AAPL",0.378571,"2013-03-31"],"3":["AAPL",0.435714,"2013-09-30"],"4":["AAPL",0.435714,"2013-12-31"],"5":["AAPL",0.47,"2014-09-30"],"6":["AAPL",0.47,"2014-12-31"],"7":["AAPL",0.52,"2015-06-30"],"8":["AAPL",0.52,"2015-09-30"],"9":["AAPL",0.52,"2015-12-31"]};

const dividends = Object.assign({}, Object.values(data)
                    .filter(([,,d], i, _, a = new Date(d)) => 
                      !_.some(([,,e], i, _, b = new Date(e)) =>
                        b.getFullYear() === a.getFullYear()
                        && b.getMonth() > a.getMonth() 
                        && b.getDate() >= a.getDate()
                        )
                    ));
          
console.log(dividends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce from the right side the sorted data by date and collect for each year and group only one data set.

```js
const
    data = { 0: ['AAPL', 0.378571, '2012-09-30'], 1: ['AAPL', 0.378571, '2012-12-31'], 2: ['AAPL', 0.378571, '2013-03-31'], 3: ['AAPL', 0.435714, '2013-09-30'], 4: ['AAPL', 0.435714, '2013-12-31'], 5: ['AAPL', 0.47, '2014-09-30'], 6: ['AAPL', 0.47, '2014-12-31'], 7: ['AAPL', 0.52, '2015-06-30'], 8: ['AAPL', 0.52, '2015-09-30'], 9: ['AAPL', 0.52, '2015-12-31'] },
    years = {},
    result = Object.assign({}, Object.assign([], data).reduceRight((r, a) => {
        if (!years[a[2].slice(0, 4)] && !r.find(b => [0, 1].every(i => a[i] === b[i]))) {
            r.push(a);
            years[a[2].slice(0, 4)] = true;
        }
        return r;
    }, []).reverse());
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```